# Cannot pass an integer - as an extra in an intent - from Unity to an Android app

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, unity-game-engine

I need to communicate an integer value from an Unity app to an Android one using an Intent. The Android app implements a receiver that expects this integer as an extra parameter in the Intent.

My Unity (C#) code looks like this:

```
int timestamp = 0; // whatever value
var playerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");             
var activity = playerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
var intent = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", ACTION_LOCK_DATE);
intent.Call("putExtra", "timestamp", timestamp);
activity.Call("sendBroadcast", intent);
```

But when running it, I get the error:

```
I/Unity   ( 4034): AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='putExtra' signature='(Ljava/lang/String;I)V' in class Landroid/content/Intent;
I/Unity   ( 4034): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='putExtra' signature='(Ljava/lang/String;I)V' in class Landroid/content/Intent;
I/Unity   ( 4034):  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
I/Unity   ( 4034):  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a(Unknown Source)
I/Unity   ( 4034):  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$b.run(Unknown Source)
```

As if it were not recognising the second *int* parameter. Any clues?
I also tried passing an object array with the String and the int, but it shows the same error. Passing it as an **Integer** instance does not work either, complaining that there is no method putExtra with with String and Integer as parameters:

```
var playerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");             
var activity = playerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
var intent = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", ACTION_LOCK_DATE);
var integerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("java.lang.Integer");
var ts = integerClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("valueOf", timestamp);
intent.Call("putExtra", "timestamp", ts);
activity.Call("sendBroadcast", intent);
```

What am I missing?
I'm going to try just parsing and passing it as a string, but I would like to avoid that and be able to pass it as a number.

Comment: Is that error the one for the first version or the second? Because it says `no method with name='putExtra'` which you said is the error for the second.

Comment: both errors are about not finding the `putExtra`, the first mentions one with a `String` as a parameter, the second time it complains about a `String` and an `Integer` (the class, not the native type).

Comment: java.lang.Integer.class != int.class and there is no method `putExtra(String name, Integer value)` but `putExtra(String name, int value)`

Comment: Yes @Selvin, I know that and if you read my question again you will see that that's the first thing I tried. My second attempt was at somehow trying to trick Unity into boxing/unboxing the value to see if that was the issue (which apparently was not).

Comment: Well ... it isn not `void putExtra(..)` but `Intent putExtra(..)` so intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", "timestamp", timestamp); should help (if exits - i dont know Unity API)

Comment: I have no experience with this, but do you really need to say `intent.Call("putExtra", "timestamp", timestamp);`? Isn't it just `intent.Call("putExtra", timestamp);`?

Comment: @GunnarB. huh? `public void Call(string methodName, params object[] args);` `Intent.putExtra` has 2 args ... so with `methodName` it makes 3 parametrs for `Call`

Comment: @Selvin As mentioned, I have no experience with that, but having the string the same as the value was giving me the thought that this might have been a try using named parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @Selvin's comment and [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/passing-androidjavaobject-as-call-parameter.218311/).
Apparently, Unity's java wrapper needs that I specify that the method returns something when invoking the `Call` method. So the problem is solved by replacing this:

```
...
intent.Call("putExtra", "timestamp", timestamp);
...
```

With this:

```
...
intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", "timestamp", timestamp);
...
```